# timestamp format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, datetime, timestamp

I am attempting at importing a CSV to MySQL.

The CSV has timestamp as

```
28/07/2016 16:00:00.
```

I need the time to be

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00 (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
```

How do I convert this in Excel prior to importing the CSV?

Or if I upload the timestamp as varchar - is there a way for me to convert it in MySQL?

Comment: select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i ');

Comment: This question addresses the time part of the datetime, the claimed duplicate does not mention time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle this on the MySQL side, you can use `LOAD DATA` while applying `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert the Excel timestamp into a format which MySQL can consume:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
INTO TABLE yourTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@c1, col2, col3, ...)
SET col1 = STR_TO_DATE(@c1, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

But personally I would rather find a way to get Excel to export the timestamps in an ANSI compliant format, i.e. year-month-day time.